# passing Data Between Different Controllers and Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two Controllers named `Home` and `Index` and two views named the same in ASP.NET-Core 3.1.

I want to pass data between Home Controller and Index View**. I tried to use `ViewBag` and `ViewData` but I can not solve the problem.

Comment: Can you share the code which you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionKeyName, "The Value You Want To Store");`

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1

You also need to set up the session first:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    });

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseSession();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, but when i try to use this way, i face the error ::                                An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HttpContext.get'

Answer (score 0):

There are two primary options here:

1. [Session and state management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1)
   If you only need the data within the session and aren’t working with enormous data objects, this is the way to go. Keep in mind in order to use session state, you need to configure it first.
   [image: Session Configuration]
2. The [Repository Pattern](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/repository-pattern-in-asp-net-core/)
   This requires a bit more setup but will allow you to maintain data outside of a session in an abstracted data layer

Answer (score 0):

You really should be passing a model instead of using viewbag or viewdata.

Define a Model like the following:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

In your HomeController create an IActionResult like the following:

```
    public IActionResult Home()
    {
        ViewModel viewmodel = new ViewModel
        {
            FirstName = "Alex",
            LastName = "Leo"
        };

        return View("/Views/Index/Index.cshtml",viewmodel);
    }
```

Your Index.cshtml will take a model passed and it will be defined as following:

```
@model ViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index Page";
}

<label>@Model.FirstName</label>
<label>@Model.LastName</label>
```

In this example when the application starts - the index page will be displayed with the passed model

[image]